# Tables not created when running unit tests with test profile

Tags: spring, postgresql-9.4

For an unknown reason, my unit tests do not work anymore. All of a sudden the tables for my test database are not being created anymore.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "app_user__user_group" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    ..
```

Let's just say that I didn't change anything, at least not to my best knowledge that should've changed that behavior, but that's just me and my relation with Spring.

So let's dump the necessary information:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")
public class AppUserRepositoryTest {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AppUserRepositoryTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    private static String USERS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/users/";
    private static String GROUPS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/groups/";
    private static String USER_LOGIN = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token/";

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();    
        LOGGER.info("Setup done.");
    }    

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
    public void whenCreateAppUser() {

        Client client = new Client();

        AppUser appUser = client.registerUser("test@example.com", "password");

        ResponseEntity<AppUser> appUserResponse = template.getForEntity(USERS_ENDPOINT + "1/", AppUser.class);

        assertEquals("Username is incorrect. AppUser not created?",
                appUser.getUsername(), appUserResponse.getBody().getUsername());
    }

}
```

Here's `application-test.properties` - or at least the relevant part:

```
# Disable feature detection by this undocumented parameter. Check the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServiceImpl.configure method for more details.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
# Because detection is disabled you have to set correct dialect by hand.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mahlzeit-test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Any idea what the problem could be? Please let me know if you need further information and/or code.